# Rancher failed to launch with the error k3s exited with: exit status 1

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I am running rancher latest docker image on Mac M1 laptop but the contact failed to start.
The command I am using is sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --privileged rancher/rancher.

Below is the versions for my environment:

$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.13, build a224086

$ uname -a
Darwin Joeys-MBP 21.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.3.0: Wed Jan 5 21:37:58 PST 2022; root:xnu-8019.80.24~20/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64

$ docker images|grep rancher
rancher/rancher latest f09cdb8a8fba 3 weeks ago 1.39GB

Below is the logs from the container.

```
$ docker logs -f 8d21d7d19b21
2022/04/28 03:34:00 [INFO] Rancher version v2.6.4 (4b4e29678) is starting
2022/04/28 03:34:00 [INFO] Rancher arguments {ACMEDomains:[] AddLocal:true Embedded:false BindHost: HTTPListenPort:80 HTTPSListenPort:443 K8sMode:auto Debug:false Trace:false NoCACerts:false AuditLogPath:/var/log/auditlog/rancher-api-audit.log AuditLogMaxage:10 AuditLogMaxsize:100 AuditLogMaxbackup:10 AuditLevel:0 Features: ClusterRegistry:}
2022/04/28 03:34:00 [INFO] Listening on /tmp/log.sock
2022/04/28 03:34:00 [INFO] Waiting for k3s to start
2022/04/28 03:34:01 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on the server ("apiserver not ready") has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/04/28 03:34:03 [INFO] Waiting for server to become available: an error on the server ("apiserver not ready") has prevented the request from succeeding
2022/04/28 03:34:05 [INFO] Running in single server mode, will not peer connections
2022/04/28 03:34:05 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:05 [INFO] Waiting for CRD features.management.cattle.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:05 [INFO] Done waiting for CRD features.management.cattle.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD navlinks.ui.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD apiservices.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterregistrationtokens.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD settings.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD preferences.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD features.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD clusterrepos.catalog.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD operations.catalog.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD apps.catalog.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD fleetworkspaces.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD bundles.fleet.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.fleet.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD managedcharts.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.provisioning.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:08 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.provisioning.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD rkeclusters.rke.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD rkecontrolplanes.rke.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD rkebootstraps.rke.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD rkebootstraptemplates.rke.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD rkecontrolplanes.rke.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD custommachines.rke.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD etcdsnapshots.rke.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD clusters.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD machinedeployments.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD machinehealthchecks.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD machines.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Applying CRD machinesets.cluster.x-k8s.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Waiting for CRD machinesets.cluster.x-k8s.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Done waiting for CRD machinesets.cluster.x-k8s.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Creating CRD authconfigs.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Creating CRD groupmembers.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Creating CRD groups.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Creating CRD tokens.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Creating CRD userattributes.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Creating CRD users.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:09 [INFO] Waiting for CRD tokens.management.cattle.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:10 [INFO] Done waiting for CRD tokens.management.cattle.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:10 [INFO] Waiting for CRD userattributes.management.cattle.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:10 [INFO] Done waiting for CRD userattributes.management.cattle.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:10 [INFO] Waiting for CRD users.management.cattle.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Done waiting for CRD users.management.cattle.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD clusterroletemplatebindings.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD apps.project.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD catalogs.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD apprevisions.project.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD dynamicschemas.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD catalogtemplates.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD pipelineexecutions.project.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD etcdbackups.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD pipelinesettings.project.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD globalrolebindings.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD pipelines.project.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD catalogtemplateversions.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD globalroles.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD sourcecodecredentials.project.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD clusteralerts.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD clusteralertgroups.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD sourcecodeproviderconfigs.project.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD kontainerdrivers.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD nodedrivers.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD clustercatalogs.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD sourcecoderepositories.project.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD clusterloggings.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD nodepools.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD nodetemplates.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD clusteralertrules.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD clustermonitorgraphs.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD clusterscans.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD nodes.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD podsecuritypolicytemplateprojectbindings.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD composeconfigs.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD podsecuritypolicytemplates.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD multiclusterapps.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD projectnetworkpolicies.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD multiclusterapprevisions.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD projectroletemplatebindings.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD monitormetrics.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD projects.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Waiting for CRD sourcecodecredentials.project.cattle.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD rkek8ssystemimages.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD notifiers.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD rkek8sserviceoptions.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD projectalerts.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD rkeaddons.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD projectalertgroups.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD roletemplates.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD projectcatalogs.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD projectloggings.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD samltokens.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD projectalertrules.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD clustertemplates.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD projectmonitorgraphs.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD clustertemplaterevisions.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD cisconfigs.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD cisbenchmarkversions.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD templates.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD templateversions.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD templatecontents.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD globaldnses.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Creating CRD globaldnsproviders.management.cattle.io
2022/04/28 03:34:11 [INFO] Waiting for CRD nodetemplates.management.cattle.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:12 [INFO] Waiting for CRD projectalertgroups.management.cattle.io to become available
2022/04/28 03:34:12 [FATAL] k3s exited with: exit status 1
```

Comment: Check issues at https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/issues

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying to run it with a specific tag, i.e. `rancher/rancher:v2.6.6`.

Some other things that may interfere: What size setup are you running on?
CPU and minimum memory requirements are currently 2 CPUs and 4gb RAM.

Also, you can try their docker install scripts and check out other documentation here: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/installation/requirements/installing-docker/

Edit: noticed you're running on ARM. There is additional documentation for running rancher on ARM here: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/installation/resources/advanced/arm64-platform/

Comment: https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/36238. The newer versions are not working properly. Had to use `2.4.9` on raspberry pi 4